# how make a clean an Input tag in htmx after some event without a form tag?

Tags: htmx

Something like receive an event from backend and clean (does not work with input for some reason)

```
<input id="todo" name="todo" type="text" placeholder="Add Todo" hx-on:myevent="this.value = '' ">
```

or something like

```
<input id="todo" name="todo" type="text" placeholder="Add Todo" hx-on="AFTER #button-id clicked: this.value = '' ">
```

I simply want to clean the input field after some event **without a form tag**
Should be such a simple task, should be possible